# Excel 2010 slow with large sets of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, performance

**Problem:**

Recently I have been working with fairly large sets of data.

However, Excel seems to handle these very slowly (it takes 3-5 minutes just to open or save the file).

**Spreadsheet details**

- Rows: 50,000
- Coloumns: 90
- Worksheets: 1
- File size: 157mb.

The sheet consists of pure data.
No formulae or VBA script has been added yet.
There are no cell references (eg =H3) or arrays.

**Specs:**
Office 2010 32 bit
Processor : i7 3.4 GHZ Quad Core
Ram : 6 Gb
Windows 7

**Steps taken thus far**

I tried saving it as an Excel binary (.xlsb) file, which helped a bit (and reduced file size a bit as well).

However, 50,000 rows is nowhere near the limit of Excel 2010 (which is 1,048,576 rows), yet it's really slow. I also remember older versions of Excel being able to deal with large chunks of data relatively fast.

Is there any way of speeding Excel up?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by _really slow_? Perhaps give an example of something you do and how long it takes. Also, while you've given us the number of rows, you haven't told us how many columns of data your working with? For example, 50,000 rows and 26 columns is a lot more data than say 50,000 rows and 3 columns, but we have no idea what your scenario is. Finally, you haven't provided the speed of your processor etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

Takes a few minutes (3-5 just to open up or save), I am worried that once I start converting it to a table and adding formulae it's going to increase significantly.  Will update my question to reflect the additional details
It's 90 coloumns.

Comment: So you have 4.5 Million different data points. I don't have an absolute answer on why your excel would be slow but at that size why not use an actual database for it? Especially if you're considering adding logic on top of it.

Comment: you should use 64-bit Office for such large set of data

Comment: Thanks for the responses, unfortunately 64 bit Office isn't an option at the moment, but I will definitely be looking into simple database solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try and mimic as closely as possible your scenario. To do this I:

- created a MS Excel spreadsheet with 50,000 rows and 90 columns of data (thankfully I work with large data sets, so this wasn't too hard to do)
- ensured the data was a mixture of formats: Text, Dates, Number and General
- did not use any formulas or VBA code

However, for me this spreadsheet was only 24MB in size, which is only about 15% of the size yours is, so I cannot account for that.

Unfortunately, the only context you've provided is the read/write speed for opening/saving your spreadsheet, so this is all I could test for. My results are as follows:

- **7.68 seconds** to save the data to a local hard drive
- **3 mins 53 seconds** to save the data to a network drive
- **10.4 seconds** to open the data from a local drive
- **50.43 seconds** to open the data from a network drive

Now, since my 50,000 rows and 90 columns of data only amounted to 24MB, my data is obviously going to take a lot less to save and load than your 157MB file (which is about 6.5 times larger).

However, as you can see, the speed of opening and saving files is not dictated purely by the size of the file itself. Working with an SSD is a lot faster than a local hard drive which in turn is a lot faster than a networked drive. Also, the type of network has a huge impact on data transfer speeds (e.g. Gigabit ethernet is a lot faster than fast ethernet).

Unfortunately, the closest computer I could find to run this test had the following specs:

- Windows 7 Enterprise (64-bit)
- i5 2.6GHz
- 8GB RAM
- MS Excel 2010 (32-bit)

**Summary**

In a nutshell:

- there are a lot of factors which impact read/write speeds, not just the amount of data but also your hardware and/or network environment
- a better test would be to see how long it takes for Excel to do some actual number crunching with your data, as opposed to read/write transfer speeds
- another factor in the case of Excel is if you're loading any add-ins etc and where they're located
- your data is 157MB in size, 6.5 times the size of my spreadsheet also containing 4.5 million cells of data (so what accounts for this?)
- install more RAM (I have worked with large data sets in Excel - Windows and Mac - for nearly two decades and the biggest factor in Excel's performance is the amount of RAM you have installed
- with 4.5 million cells of data you may need to reconsider whether a database would serve your needs better

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort for troubleshooting, I truly appreciate it.

I tried reducing the data size by saving it to a .csv and .txt formats (in an attempt to remove any formatting I am not aware of) however it didn't help reduce the file size.

I'll take your advise,  is there any database programs you'd recommend for database beginners?

Comment: Well, if you've already got MS Access as part of MS Office, you could use that. There are lots of resources to get you started and it's well worth putting the effort into. You can even create your database by importing your current Excel data.

Answer (score 1):

Spreadsheet is definitely not the right tool to handler large set of data because cell are loaded as object in memory (a very inefficient way).

You can use CSV (or TSV) format for your data and use dedicated tools to manipulate them. Such as open-refine or GNU awk, etc.

EDIT : I recently tried [visidata](https://www.visidata.org/) on quite large dataset (1.7GB, 300k+ lines) with success. Very convenient quickly to slice and dice.

Answer (score -3):

*emphasized text*The fastest approach to handling large volumes of data is to use DataCollections to consolidate the data before making it available for Excel to process. I have used this technique extensively and it is simple to code and much faster to run than asking Excel to process large volumes of data.

```vb
'Copy/Paste the following text into an Excelcode Module
'Consider a large dataset containing 5 years files of Date/customer account number/customer name/5 x address/phone number/invoice value
'and where customers may issue more than one invoice per day.
'Let's assume the business requirement is to provide a report of total value per customer by year/month.
'Rather than placing these records in an Excel worksheet, use VB to read the 5 yearly files and consolidate the information in a memory
'collection by year/month rather than year/month/day.
'If there were, say, 300,000 records this would result in a maximum of 60,000 records:- 5 years x 12 months x 1,000 customers.
'at the same time any rows or columns not contributing to the report can be excluded. (10 columns reduced to 4 in this example)
'and the Excel 1 million row limit would not apply unless the consolidated data exceeded this limit.
'With 300,000 rows and 10 columns of data, Excel has 3 million cells to process.
'Consolidation reduces the data to 60,000 rows and 4 columns i.e. 240,000 cells.
'Therefore Excel has 3,000,000 / 240,000 = 12.5% of the data to process which will directly impact runtime.
'The code below assumes the data is already held in an Excel worksheet but this could easily be converted to reading from one or more files.
'Using a Collection to consolidate the data results in Excel having far less data to process and less data means less time to process.
'I have used the Collection Class for 20 years but heard recently that there is also a Dictionary class which has benefits over the Collections class.
'I have never used this class but see details https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/3391/Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'First create an empty .xlsm Workbook containing sheet Data and Sheet Consolidation
'then create a Class record of only those data fields required for analysis (i.e. not address and phone number in this example)
'by Cut and pasting the following definitions into Class1 which specifies the Collection memory record format
'containing only those data elements required for analysis (i.e. not address and phone number)
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Option Explicit
'Private pYYMM As String
'Private pAccountNumber As String
'Private pCustomerName As String
'Private pTotalValue As Single
''
'Property Let YYMM(xx As String)                     'YYMM
'    pYYMM = xx
'End Property
'Property Get YYMM() As String
'    YYMM = pYYMM
'End Property
'Property Let AccountNumber(xx As String)              'AccountNumber
'    pAccountNumber = xx
'End Property
'Property Get AccountNumber() As String
'    AccountNumber = pAccountNumber
'End Property
'Property Let CustomerName(xx As String)              'CustomerName
'    pCustomerName = xx
'End Property
'Property Get CustomerName() As String
'    CustomerName = pCustomerName
'End Property
'Property Let TotalValue(xx As Single)                   'TotalValue
'    pTotalValue = xx
'End Property
'Property Get TotalValue() As Single
'    TotalValue = pTotalValue
'End Property
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'and remove the first ' comment on each row
'then, in a Code module, declare the Collection::-
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Option Explicit
Dim NewRecord As New Class1                  'record area (definition of new Class1 record)
Dim Class1Collection As New Collection       'A collection of keyed records held in memory
Dim Class1Key As String                      'Collection Key must be a String
Dim WalkRecord As Class1
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Next create the text key used to access each Class1 record in memory by year, month and account number:-
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim Rw As Long
Dim StartTime As Date
Sub Consolidate()
    StartTime = Now()
    Sheets("Data").Select
    For Rw = 2 To Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
            Class1Key = Format(Range("A" & Rw).Value, "yymm") & Range("B" & Rw).Value               'Key = yymm & AccountNumber
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Next populate the Class1 record:-
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            NewRecord.YYMM = Format(Range("A" & Rw).Value, "yymm")              'YYMM
            NewRecord.AccountNumber = Range("B" & Rw).Value                     'AccountNumber
            NewRecord.CustomerName = Range("C" & Rw).Value                      'CustomerName
            NewRecord.TotalValue = Range("J" & Rw).Value                        'TotalValue
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Next write the Class record into memory and, if an identical key already exists, accumulate TotalValue:-
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            On Error Resume Next
            Call Class1Collection.Add(NewRecord, Class1Key)
            Select Case Err.Number
                Case Is = 0
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    '******** NEW RECORD INSERTED OK HERE *********
                Case Is = 457
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    '******** CONSOLIDATE DUPLICATE KEY CASES HERE  ************
                    Class1Collection(Class1Key).TotalValue = Class1Collection(Class1Key).TotalValue + NewRecord.TotalValue
                Case Else
                    '******** UNEXPECTED ERROR *****************
                    Err.Raise Err.Number
                    Stop
            End Select
            Set NewRecord = Nothing
    Next Rw
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' When all the records have been processed, write Collection entries to a WorkSheet:-
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Sheets("Consolidation").Select
    Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("Date", "account number", "customer name", "total value")
    Rw = 2
    For Each WalkRecord In Class1Collection                                 'walk collection and write rows
        Cells(Rw, 1) = "20" & Left(WalkRecord.YYMM, 2) & "/" & Right(WalkRecord.YYMM, 2)
        Cells(Rw, 2) = WalkRecord.AccountNumber
        Cells(Rw, 3) = WalkRecord.CustomerName
        Cells(Rw, 4) = WalkRecord.TotalValue
        Rw = Rw + 1
    Next WalkRecord
    Set Class1Collection = Nothing
    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Columns("A:D").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
'
    Range("A2").Select
    Rw = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidation").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidation").Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("A2:A" & Rw), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidation").Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("B2:B" & Rw), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidation").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:D" & Rw)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    MsgBox ("Runtime " & Format(Now() - StartTime, "hh:mm:ss"))     '300k records takes 1 min 46 seconds on my ancient HP laptop
End Sub
'
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Now run macro Generate to create 300k test rows, followed by macro Consolidate to demonstrate consolidation by data collection.
'In my experience the improvement in Excel run time for producing any reports is so spectacular that no further action is required
'but further run time improvements could result from avoiding calling the Format function twice every row,
'or holding CustomerName in another collection and accessing during the Walk process, or using the Dictionary class
'Note that is advisable to run macro ClearSheets before saving your WorkBook.
'Also the Record constant can be manually adjust up to a maximum of 1048575 if required
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'
Sub Generate()                                  'Generates test data in Sheet Data
Const StartDate As Date = 42370                 '01/01/2016
Const FinishDate  As Date = 44196               '31/12/2020
Const Records As Long = 300000                  'number of records to generate - max 1,048,575
Const Customers As Integer = 1000               'number of Customers
Const StartValue As Integer = 5                 '£5
Const FinishValue As Integer = 100              '£100
    StartTime = Now()
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1:J1").Value = Array("Date", "account number", "customer name", "address 1", "address 2", "address 3", "address 4", "address 5", "phone number", "invoice value")
    For Rw = 2 To Records + 1
        Cells(Rw, 1) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(StartDate, FinishDate)     'Date
        Cells(Rw, 2) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, Customers)              'Customer number
        Range(Cells(Rw, 3), Cells(Rw, 9)) = Array("Customer " & Cells(Rw, 2), "Not required", "Not required", "Not required", "Not required", "Not required", "Not required")
        Cells(Rw, 10) = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(StartValue, FinishValue)  'Value
    Next Rw
    Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"
    Columns("J:J").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Columns("A:J").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select
    MsgBox ("Runtime " & Format(Now() - StartTime, "hh:mm:ss"))     '300k records takes 1 min 50 seconds on my ancient HP laptop
End Sub
Sub ClearSheets()                                   'delete all data before saving
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Consolidation").Select
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Finally, a data collection can comprise of keys and value without a Class record.
'Such a collection can be used to identify data duplicates (e.g. key=cellcontent/row number) or hold a lookup table (e.g. key=account/name)
'Most applications process far more data than they report therefore using collections benefits most data sets irrespective of volume.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).